# function not responding with desired result?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I'm able to create a PL/pgSQL function successfully. But while running a function it response like below

```sql
SELECT  __find_locations() 

Successfully run. Total query runtime: 236 msec.
867 rows affected.
```

*But I'm expecting it to return 867 rows*

My function looks like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.__find_locations() 
    RETURNS TABLE (j json) AS
    $$
        BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT row_to_json(data) from 
            (SELECT geonameid, latitude, longitude, country_code, country_name, 
             FROM public.locations) AS data; 
        END
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Any kind of help will much be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: no data is returning while running `SELECT  __find_locations() `

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that query? Maybe that tool truncates large results.

Comment: I'm using pgAdmin

Comment: while running `SELECT * FROM locations` I'm able to get the data, then what's wrong with the above functions

Comment: A table function should be used like a table. Does it work if you use `select * from __find_locations()`

Comment: Nope, `select * from __find_locations()` also not working.. it is also returning the same result

Comment: Please review help section [mre] and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Now it is returning result. I don't know why it not worked at that time